# How do I set an object's rotation to match a Vive controller rotation upon trigger using A-Frame?

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation, aframe

Using the project [A-Frame Dominoes](https://github.com/bryik/aframe-dominoes) as an example, I'm creating a basic A-Frame application that spawns objects when the Vive trigger is pressed.

I can get the newly spawned object to match the Vive's controller position at the time of trigger, however I can't figure out a way to match the rotation of the new object to the rotation of the controller.

Here's what I've tried:

```
onTriggerDown: function () {
  var sceneEl = d3.select(this.el.sceneEl);
  var controllerWorldPosition = this.el.object3D.getWorldPosition();
  var controllerWorldRotation = this.el.object3D.getWorldRotation();

  sceneEl.append('a-obj-model')
         .attr('id', 'base-street-children')
         .attr('scale', '0.01 0.01 0.01')
         .attr('position', controllerWorldPosition)
         .attr('rotation', controllerWorldRotation)
         .attr('src', '#base-street-obj')
         .attr('mtl', '#base-street-mtl');
},
```

Is there something special about setting a new object's rotation with JavaScript that I'm missing?

Comment: Can you check if the world position / rotation values look correct? Looks correct at a glance. A longshot might be to convert to Vector3 to a plain {x, y, z} JavaScript object.

Comment: They do look correct and I've added logging to the function to spit out rotation both as a js object and as the string Euler values for x, y and z.
`rotation:  THREE.Euler_order: NaN_x: 0.9155754789964565_y: 0.40301867851568707_z: -0.606638077169057order: (...)x: (...)y: (...)z: (...)__proto__: Object`
`rotation: 0.9155754789964565 0.40301867851568707 -0.606638077169057`
`position:  THREE.Vector3x: -0.5138129591941833y: 0.35001492500305176z: -0.3904404938220978__proto__: Object
OBJLoader.js:558 OBJLoader: 1.000ms`

Comment: I tried to set the new object's rotation attribute from the string components of Euler rotation but not having success either. Here is that code: `.attr('rotation', controllerWorldRotation._x + ' ' + controllerWorldRotation._y + ' ' + controllerWorldRotation._z)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Three.js, rotation is in radians, but in A-Frame rotation is in degrees. Since you are pulling out rotation data from a Three.js Object3D you will need to convert before applying it to an A-Frame entity.

Here is how this might be done in your example:

```
.attr('rotation', function() {
  var controllerWorldRotationX = controllerWorldRotation._x / (Math.PI / 180);
  var controllerWorldRotationY = controllerWorldRotation._y / (Math.PI / 180);
  var controllerWorldRotationZ = controllerWorldRotation._z / (Math.PI / 180);

  return controllerWorldRotationX + ' ' + controllerWorldRotationY + ' ' + controllerWorldRotationZ;
})
```